# Better unlocking schemes?

Tags: lock-screens

On my Galaxy S3 I have only a few options for locking/unlocking:

Either no locking and swiping, or entering a pin every time. Both options are not very attractive. One is too insecure when leaving it somewhere, the other too cumbersome, when I just take it out of my pocket. OK, there are more options, like face recognition and all that, but it never works in the dark.

What I would like to have is a more intelligent scheme: That I do not have to unlock as long as my S3 stays close to me. That a pin is only required, when it is further away from me.

Is something like that available or possible?  Maybe in conjunction with an RFID-chip? Or bluetooth? So I would carry in another pocket that other device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like [NFCSecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.t3hh4xx0r.nfcsecure).
You can combine normal lock screen (i.e. swiping) with an underlaying NFCSecure lock screen for better security (only lets you in when scanned the needed NFC tag).
Your smartphone needs NFC capabilities and you need an NFC tag to carry around with you to unlock your phone.
Can not test this as my phone doesn't have NFC capabilities.

Comment: I just watched the demo: I will have to hold my phone very close to the phone. Is this right?

Comment: @false Yes, it must be pretty close to the tag I think. But you can also put a small sticker onto the back of your watch or put something like [this](http://www.buynfctags.com/nfc-key-fob-ultralight.html) at your keys - maybe it would work through your pants pockets?! I think the max distance should be about 4cm max (as written in [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication)). You have to try it out what works best for you daily need.

Answer (score 1):

It also could be achieved with some bluetooth device (a headset should do), and using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm):

- **Condition:** Bluetooth Connected<sup>1</sup>
- **Task:** Keyguard "off"

<sup>1</sup> Easiest set up with the device connected, so you can select it here

Of course this would require your BT headset to be permanently on -- plus connected to your body :). Then, as long as the two are in reach of each other, you wouldn't need to enter your PIN. But as soon as the connection is broken (you're separated beyond the BT range), Keyguard would be enabled again, and the PIN required to unlock.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow get a hint about the proximity of the devices?

Comment: That often depends on *both* devices. You can try to figure out for yourself: connect the headset, put in on a table, and then slowly move away with your phone. When the headset symbol disappears, you've left the range. Move closer again very slowly until it shows up again. Somewhere between the two positions is your max-range. Note that the range might differ depending on whether you're in plain-sight, or have a ferro-concrete wall in between, for example :)